# How to generate the extent report in pdf instead of html

Tags: extentreports

My req is to generate the extent report in pdf file instead of HTML. I am using the Page object model not the cucumber one   . any clue please let me know

Looking for the solution as client requirement and any one did it please do share the info.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one: Extent Report pdf, if you are working on Java
https://github.com/grasshopper7/extent-pdf-report